# How an interface can replace a class?

Tags: c#, list, generics, interface, ilist

I created a Method called `GetStudentMarks()`. The return-type of this method is generic `List<StudentMark>`.The code works well even when i replaced the `List<StudentMark>` with generic `IList<StudentMark>`. How can an interface replace a class while interface contain only the declarations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An interface cannot replace a class. It's just a blueprint for a class that has some implementation that corresponds by the guidelines that are set by the interface. So, you mostly will have one interface and than 1 or multiple classes that have some implementation for that interface like so:

```
public interface IMyInterface{
 IList<string> SomeList { get; }
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface {
  public IList<string> SomeList {
    get { 
      return new List<string>(){ "a", "b" , "c" }; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, although the term "Contract" is more established. The interface promises that an object can perform a certain kind of methods.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if the return type is interface or a solid class. Since inside the method you're returning the full type, the type is casted to the declared return type before returning the actual data so everything works as expected.

```
public IList<string> MyStrings()
{
  return new List<string>(); // Cast happens here just before return (List -> IList)
}
```

Later if you require, you can cast the return type (IList) back to the solid class (List) and use it that way.

Answer (score 1):

`Interface` can not replace the `Class`. `Interface` can create an *abstraction layer* that hides actual object implementation beyound interface (that's why it's called *interface*). 
Look on [Polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for explanation.

Comment: Just to rephrase you a little, it hides or abstracts the *implementation* of what it defines.